# Flask-WTForms .validate_on_submit() never executes

Tags: flask-wtforms, wtforms

So basically I want to have a Updateform() form that allows users to update their account details. All my other forms (register, etc.) work perfectly fine but this specific form never validates on submit. Hence when I press the submit button the page just refreshes but the .validate_on_submit() code doesn't execute.

I've looked through the forums and a common issue I found is the .CSRF token missing, but I'm using form.hidden_tag() which I read should work perfectly fine. So it seems that my issue is unique.

I've been looking on the forums for hours but haven't found a solution.

Here is my form code:

```
class Updateform(FlaskForm):

    email = StringField('Email:', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    picture = FileField('Update Profile Picture:', validators=[FileAllowed(['jpg', 'png'])])
    submit = SubmitField("Update")


    def validate_email(self, email):
        if email.data != User.email:
            if User.query.filter_by(email=email.data).first():
                raise ValidationError('Email has already been registered')
```

Here is the route:

```
@users.route('/account', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def account():
    form = Updateform()
    print("hello")

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print(form)
        print("YES!!!")
        name = current_user.name
        pic = add_profile_pic(form.picture.data, name)
        current_user.profile_image = pic

        current_user.email = form.email.data
        db.session.commit()
        flash("Account Updated")

    # elif request.method == "GET":
    #     form.email = current_user.email

    profile_image = url_for('static', filename='profile_pics/'+current_user.profile_image)
    return render_template('account.html', profile_image=profile_image, form=form)
```

And here is the html code:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

    <div align="center">
        Hi {{ current_user.name }}<br>
        <img align="center" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='profile_pics/'+current_user.profile_image) }}">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <form method="post">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.email.label(class='form-group') }}
                {{ form.email(class='form-control') }}
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.picture.label(class='form-group') }}
                {{ form.picture(class='form-control') }}
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.submit() }}
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

The extra classes you see are from the bootstrap library incase anyone is wondering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello you could find out what the problem is by adding a else for you `if form.validate_on_submit():` and have it do this

```
for error in form.email.errors:
    print(error)
for error in form.picture.errors:
    print(error)
```

this should tell you what is not working hope this helps and I have not tested this so it could have typos